# how would a group by an sql query like this

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this query.

I would like to to group the result  by getting userid and albumtemplateid only, but and the cardtenplateid column I would like to get one of many values that the column have.

```
Select 
   UserID, 
   CardTemplateID, 
   AlbumTemplateID
from vwCardsPerUser
```

I don't know if i made myself clear but  here is a example:

userid     cardtemplateid     albumtemplateid
1                   3                                       1
2                   2                                                     1
1                 7                                                     1
3                   3                                                     2

so the result would be:
userid     cardtemplateid     albumtemplateid
1              3                                          1
2              2                                          1
3              3                                          2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which "one of many" `cardtemplateid` values you'd want returned, I arbitrarily chose to select the minimum value.

```
SELECT userid, albumtemplateid, MIN(cardtemplateid)
    FROM vwCardsPerUser
    GROUP BY userid, albumtemplateid;
```

**EDIT** Based on the question in the comment, this handles the case where cardtemplateid is a uniqueidentifier data type:

```
WITH cteCards AS (
    SELECT userid, albumtemplateid, cardtemplateid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid, albumtemplateid ORDER BY cardtemplateid) AS RowNum
        FROM vwCardsPerUser
)
SELECT userid, albumtemplateid, cardtemplateid
    FROM cteCards
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: it works great!! but i have another question. I have some tables that uses uniqueidentifiers as the id and I can't use nor MAX nor MIN is there a work around?

Comment: @ShadowG: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 9.00.5057.00 - SP4 (Workgroup Edition)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Select  UserID , max(CardTemplateID) as CardTemplateID
    ,AlbumTemplateID  
from vwCardsPerUser
    group by UserID, AlbumTemplateID
```

use max or min on cardtemplateid and group by userid and albumtemplateid ... this will work fine....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following query.:

```
SELECT UserID AS userid, 
       MAX(CardTemplateID) AS cardtemplateid, 
       AlbumTemplateID AS albumtemplateid
FROM vwCardsPerUser 
GROUP BY userid, albumtemplateid
```

The `MAX` aggregate function applied to CardTemplateID allows it to participate in this query. You need to use an aggregate function on the column, because it is not present in the `GROUP BY` clause.